# Using the standard C library or POSIX library to scan for a file in a UNIX directory

Tags: c, unix

Is there anyway for a C program to view the files in a certain directory and interface with them? For example, lets say that I downloaded a file using wget via the system() function, and I want to see what the file's name was. Is there any way for me to accomplish this through only the standard C library or the POSIX library?

Comment: The C standard library has no concept of a file system, so no. In Posix, use `<dirent.h>`.

Comment: Two standard functions are [stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) and [readdir()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir).

Comment: The question is, how will you recognize the file when you see it? IMHO, it would be better to use a network library, like libcurl (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), to download the URL into a file whose name you select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks for files in a directory that were modified less than 5 seconds ago - there is NO error checking.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void dirchk(const char *arg)  // arg=name of directory
{
    time_t when = time(NULL) -5; // 5 secs ago
    struct stat st;
    DIR *dirp=opendir(arg);
    struct dirent *d=readdir(dirp);
    while (d != NULL)
    {
        if ((d = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) 
        {
            stat(d->d_name, &st);
            if( when - st.st_mtime  <=5 )
               printf("%s\n", d->d_name);
        }
    } 
    closedir(dirp);
    return;
}

int main()
{
   dirchk(".");
   return 0;
}
```

"." is the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will read up on dirent.h and the time() function.